# how do i Fix the upstream dependency conflict without using --force or --legacy-peer-deps on my expo go project

Tags: npm, expo, eas

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-reanimated-carousel@3.5.1
npm ERR! Found: react-native-reanimated@2.14.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-reanimated
npm ERR!   react-native-reanimated@"~2.14.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-reanimated@">= 1.0.0" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.6.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (react-native-circular-progress-indicator, react-native-redash)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-reanimated@">=3.0.0" from react-native-reanimated-carousel@3.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-reanimated-carousel
npm ERR!   react-native-reanimated-carousel@"^3.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-reanimated@3.5.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-reanimated
npm ERR!   peer react-native-reanimated@">=3.0.0" from react-native-reanimated-carousel@3.5.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-reanimated-carousel
npm ERR!     react-native-reanimated-carousel@"^3.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! D:\Programs\node_modules\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-22T06_16_20_315Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: D:\Programs\node_modules\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-22T06_16_20_315Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm trying to eas build, but there is an conflict in dependency. `npm install exited with non-zero code: 1`

the problem can be bypass using --force or --legacy-peer-deps but it seems like not resolve the problems itself.

i already tried using npm config set legacy-peer-deps true.

but i think its not how u solve the problem

> In summary, the error indicates a conflict in the versions of react-native-reanimated required by different packages in your project.Need to adjust your dependencies or use the suggested flags to force the installation.

I solved the question by using npm ls react-native-reanimated and just remove the conflicted packages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to your package.json and in the deependancies section add:

```
    "react-native-reanimated" : "^3.0.0"
```

run `npm install` again and you should be good. If not, post your package.json.

As a sidenote, please use proper formatting for code and error messages in the future. When you post it as plaintext in one huge blob, it just becomes impossible to read.

UPDATE:
It looks like `react-native-svg-charts` is not compatible with all the other stuff. If it is removed, then it will install. I don't know why `react-native-svg-charts` is incompatible, but right now I don't think there is a solution besides removing it.

This is the set of packages I was able to find that do actually install:

```
+-- @babel/core@7.23.3
+-- @babel/preset-env@7.23.3
+-- @react-native-community/datetimepicker@6.7.5
+-- @react-native-picker/picker@2.4.8
+-- @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.11
+-- @react-navigation/core@6.4.10
+-- @react-navigation/drawer@6.6.6
+-- @react-navigation/elements@1.3.21
+-- @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs@6.2.19
+-- @react-navigation/material-top-tabs@6.6.5
+-- @react-navigation/native-stack@6.9.17
+-- @react-navigation/native@6.1.9
+-- @react-navigation/routers@6.1.9
+-- @react-navigation/stack@6.3.20
+-- ascii-horizontal-barchart@1.3.3
+-- axios@1.6.2
+-- chart-react-native@1.0.1
+-- dotenv@16.3.1
+-- expo-document-picker@11.2.2
+-- expo-font@11.1.1
+-- expo-image-picker@14.1.1
+-- expo-image@1.0.2
+-- expo-linear-gradient@12.1.2
+-- expo-secure-store@12.1.1
+-- expo-sqlite@11.1.1
+-- expo-status-bar@1.4.4
+-- expo-storage@48.1.0
+-- expo@48.0.21
+-- native-base@3.4.28
+-- react-native-chart-kit@6.12.0
+-- react-native-circular-progress-indicator@4.4.2
+-- react-native-config@1.5.1
+-- react-native-dotenv@3.4.9
+-- react-native-gesture-handler@2.9.0
+-- react-native-loading-modal@1.1.0
+-- react-native-mmkv-storage@0.9.1
+-- react-native-mmkv@2.11.0
+-- react-native-progress-steps@1.3.4
+-- react-native-reanimated-carousel@3.5.1
+-- react-native-reanimated@3.5.4
+-- react-native-safe-area-context@4.5.0
+-- react-native-screens@3.20.0
+-- react-native-snap-carousel@3.9.1
+-- react-native-sqlite-storage@6.0.1
+-- react-native-svg@14.0.0
+-- react-native-toast-message@2.1.7
+-- react-native-vector-icons@10.0.2
+-- react-native@0.71.14
+-- react@18.2.0
+-- victory-native@36.6.12
`-- victory@36.6.12
```

Comment: i already tried your suggestion, after i tried npm install it's still remains. Wait lemme add my package.json

Comment: how do i add the package.json file ?

Comment: @PatrickLay Just copy and paste it into your question

Comment: it says : It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. :/

Comment: @PatrickLay In this case, the code is required. Maybe just write a couple sentences about the weather so that SO lets you submit?

Comment: done, can u check what make it conflict? i have no idea just new into expo go :/

Comment: I'll work on it, but just FYI it might take an hour or more because I'm just answering SO questions in between other tasks.

Comment: @PatrickLay It looks like you can't have the react-native-svg-charts If you remove it, it installs

Comment: after i change the version of  "react-native-reanimated" : "^3.0.0"  theres an error : 
 Error: [Reanimated] Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated (3.5.4 vs 2.14.4).
See `https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#mismatch-between-javascript-part-and-native-part-of-reanimated` for more details., js engine: hermes